# Seam:token tag not being respected

Tags: jsf, seam, ajax4jsf

When I click a command button, and then hit the browser back button to the form and click it again, it submits a second time without throwing the proper exception...

Even stranger, the form id itself is DIFFERENT when I come back, which implies it has regenerated a "valid" form id at some point.

Here's the relevant code: Any ideas?

```
<h:form id="accountActivationForm">
    <s:token/>
    <a4j:commandButton id="cancelActivateAccountButton"
        action="#{controller[cancelAction]}"
    image="/images/button-Cancel-gray.gif"
        reRender="#{reRenderList}"
        oncomplete="#{onCancelComplete}" />
        &#160;
    <a4j:commandButton id="activateAccountButton"
        action="#{controller[agreeAction]}"
        image="/images/button-i-agree-continue.gif"
        styleClass="activate-account-button"
        reRender="#{reRenderList}"
        oncomplete="#{onActivationComplete}"/>
</h:form>
```

Clarifications:

- I inherited this, so I'm trying to change it as little as possible.  (It's used in a couple places.)
- Each action returns a view, not null. I have confirmed this by stepping through line-by-line.
- The reRenderList is empty in my current test-case.
- onActivationComplete is also empty.

I'm going to be going template-by-template to see if someone made it with nested forms, because my coworkers have had unrelated problems due to that, so it couldn't hurt to eliminate that as a possible problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `s:token` is supposed to avoid double/multiple submits by impatiently clicking the submit button multiple times in the same request or by refreshing the non-redirected result in the webbrowser or by resubmitting the *cached* page in the browser history.

That it works when the client navigates back and forth by browser history just means that the pages with the forms are *not* cached in client's browser history and are requested as brand new from the server side again. That would indeed return a new token. Check it yourself with a HTTP tracker like the one in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com).

Comment: ok, so why does it reload when I click the back button? What is the best way to prevent the form being submitted again (since it's not the same form)?

Comment: The back button will re-execute the request if it is not been cached by the browser. I.e. the request has at least `Cache-Control: no-cache`, `Pragma: no-cache` and `Expires: 0` in the response headers.